# Trouble getting JOptionPane to open up an image from a website

Tags: java, joptionpane

I want to get JOptionPane to open up images from a link, because I have an assignment due next week where I have to include images in JOptionPane, and while it works with local files I'm not sure if that'll show when I turn it in. Anyways, what I have is:

```
ImageIcon thing = new ImageIcon("http://i.imgur.com/OGxr68g.jpg");
       String[] finalOutputChoices = {"Help", "Please"};         
   int finalOutput = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog( 
           null                                 // 
           , "Message"                          // 
           , "Final Output"                     // 
           , JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION          //
           , JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE          //
           , thing                              //
           , finalOutputChoices                 // 
           , "Awesome"                          // 
   );
```

If I replace the link with the path to an image on my desktop it works, but it doesn't with the link.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works with a URL object.

```
ImageIcon thing = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://i.imgur.com/OGxr68g.jpg"));
```

PS: weird image ;-)